# How to get an empty (i.e. no-value) attribute in an HTML element in coffeekup's output?

Tags: angularjs, coffeekup

I'm trying to get started with AngularJS using coffeescript and coffeekup.

AngularJS is capable of [auto-bootstrapping itself](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) when it detects the `ng-app` attribute on any HTML element. According to the docs, it should be placed on the `<html>` or `<body>` element. However, it will try to load any attribute value, if given, as the application root module.

When placed on the `<html>` element for example, the HTML should be

```
<html ng-app>
```

This output does not seem to be achievable using coffeekup. I tried the following things:

```
html 'ng-app': ''    #prints <html></html>
html '': 'ng-app'    #prints <html ="ng-app"></html>
html 'ng-app': ' '   #prints <html ng-app=" "></html> (still not what is wanted)
```

To clarify: What I do **not** want is the following:

```
html 'ng-app': 'ng-app' #prints <html ng-app="ng-app"></html>
```

since this causes AngularJS to look for a non-existent root module called `ng-app`.

Currently, I'm defining an empty root module as a workaround, but I still don't think that this is something coffeekup is not capable of.

Comment: did you tried escaping `html 'ng-app': '\'\''` ??

Comment: Thanks, but this leads to `<html ng-app="''">` - whereas the wanted output is `<html ng-app>`